# Postgres NodeJS bulk upsert timeout

Tags: node.js, postgresql, pg

I'm trying to insert a CSV of 10k rows into Postgres. It works for the first 400 rows, then I get the below error:

```
"Error: connection terminated"
```

I'm not sure how to debug this as the error is pretty generic. Here is my code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;
const csvFilePath='../../li.csv' 
const csv=require('csvtojson') 

async function run(){
const jsonArray=await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
let datas=[];

jsonArray.map((item)=>{
    datas.push(item);
})

// create a new connection to the database
const pool = new Pool({
    host: "host",
    user: "host",
    database: "db",
    password: "host",
    port: 5432
    });

    const query =
    "INSERT INTO table_name (profile, name, tle, loc, rel, current, time) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7)";

    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
        if (err) throw err;
  
        try {
          datas.forEach(row => {

            client.query(query, [row.profile, row.name, row.tle, row.loc, row.rel, row.current, row.time], (err, res) => {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err.stack);
              } else {
                console.log("inserted " + res.rowCount + " row:", row);
              }
            });
          });
        } finally {
          done();
        }
      })
    }

    run();
```

Comment: Look in the database server's log file for a possibly better error message.

Comment: Your title says "timeout". But the error does not.  So why do you think that?